# Problems with last android system update (network SSID)

Tags: java, android, updates, ico, ssid

I developed a simple software for my companies tablets (SAMSUNG  Galaxy Tab Active2) and since last Friday (11/23/2018) it doesn't work properly. I checked all the  functionalities of the application and there are two of them that don't work.

For start, the application can't get the SSID network.
I use the follow routine:

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
if (wifiInfo.getSSID().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("networkname")) {}
else {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Make sure you're connected to networkname.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
```

This code used to work perfectly fine until last Friday. I tried to get the SSID network and got the result `<unknown SSID>`. Also I connected the tablet to some different networks and got always the same result.

Then I noted another thing has happened: the personalized application icon changed to the default android system icon.

I managed to pinpoint the problem with the last system update: `Samsung Experience 9.0 (Android Oreo) version T395XXU3BRJ5/T395OXXU3BRJ1/T395XXU3BRJ5`. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problems? Or how to point me on that direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can notice in other threads, the problem about "unknow SSID" in android > 8.1 is related to a new security patch that deny access to SSID info without RUNTIME EXPLICIT PERMISSION of LOCATION ( FINE_LOCATON, COARSE_LOCATION ). Simply set up a request permission function that runtime will call user attention to enable location. Hope it helps, even though since some time has passed, maybe you already found the solution

Comment: Indeed I already have found the solution... Thanks anyway. I will accept your answer.